# Representation theory of symmetric groups over Q-algebras

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $k$ be a commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, and let $\Sigma_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters. What is known about the classification of $k$-linear representations of $\Sigma_n$? (Of course, it will not be as concrete as the classification as in the case that $k$ is a field, but we may treat $k$-modules as already been classified and that these may be part of the classification data.) Can someone point me to relevant literature on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standard representation theory of $\Sigma_n$, it follows that the group algebra $\mathbb{Q}\Sigma_n$ is a product of matrix rings over $\mathbb{Q}$.

So $k\Sigma_n\cong\mathbb{Q}\Sigma_n\otimes_\mathbb{Q}k$ is a corresponding product of matrix rings over $k$, which is Morita equivalent to a product of copies of $k$.

Concretely, if $V_1,\dots,V_r$ are the irreducible $\mathbb{Q}\Sigma_n$-modules, then the $k\Sigma_n$-modules are of the form 
$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^r M_i\otimes_\mathbb{Q}V_i,$$
where $M_1,\dots,M_r$ are $k$-modules.

Comment: Thank you! The number of irreducibles is not $n$, though. Is it correct that we don't need any finiteness conditions on the modules here?

Comment: @HeinrichD Sorry, I didn't notice I was using $n$ for two different things: I've fixed that. Yes, it's correct that no finiteness conditions are needed.

Comment: Alright. But the category of $k$-linear representations is semisimple iff $k$ is a field, right? Do you have a textbook reference to your classification? Assume that I use this somewhere in a paper, do I need a reference or does anybody know this? At least I knew this only for fields $k$.

Comment: @HeinrichD It's not quite if and *only* if $k$ is a field: the category of $k$-linear representations is semisimple iff $k$ is semisimple. I'm afraid I don't know a reference that states all of this explicitly: if you use this in a paper, why not just include a sentence or two explaining why it's true.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One final question: All this remains true for $\mathbb{Z}[1/n!]$-algebras $k$, right?

Comment: @HeinrichD That sounds plausible, although I can't immediately see a proof.