# Reference request: Representation theory over fields of characteristic zero

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, young-tableaux, algebraic-combinatorics

Many representation theory textbooks and online resources work with the field of complex numbers or more generally algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero. I am looking for a good textbook on representation theory which works with fields of characteristic zero directly from the beginning. (In case there are many such textbooks, I would prefer "modern" ones which emphasize the theory of non-commutative algebras; it should really be the opposite of Fulton-Harris.) In particular, it should mention the classification of irreducible representations of symmetric groups over $\mathbb{Q}$, and there should be more than just a side remark that those over $\mathbb{C}$ descend to  $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: the representations are rational, as shown in most good texts.

Comment: @Darj I thought the geometric representation of $S_3$ could not be realized with rational matrices. I suppose it is just too early in the morning for me to be commenting here.

Comment: @Darij I still cannot see how to realize the $2$-dimensional one over the rationals. Am I missing some obvious choice of basis?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Takeone of the geometrically obvious bases, and just multiply one of the basis elements by $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks, I really should have been able to see that.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: See the Wildon notes I reference in my answer for a proper treatment of the representation theory over any(!) field. It is not fully self-contained, but at least the simples are constructed in full generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book *"The representation theory of the symmetric group"* (Encyclopedia of
Mathematics and its Applications, Vol. 16, Addison-Wesley, Reading, Mass., 1981), by Gordon James and Adalbert Kerber, develops the characteristic zero representation theory of symmetric groups over $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular it has a theorem (Theorem 2.1.12) explicitly stating that every field is a splitting field for $S_n$.

Comment: Theorem 2.1.12 (about "every field", not just every characteristic-$0$ field) relies on Corollary (83.7) in Curtis-Reiner (the single-volume book) though, and that's a rather advanced result whose proof relies on number fields.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of references that should be somewhat useful. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a single reference that takes you reasonably far all by itself -- and I'd much like to!

- [Martin Lorenz, *A tour of representation theory*](https://www.math.temple.edu/~lorenz/book.html) (a draft, but most of the text is fully fleshed out already) does lots of general representation theory in high generality. Unfortunately, as it comes to symmetric groups, it relies on algebraic closedness due to its use of the Okounkov-Vershik approach. Still, you should be able to extract a lot of good material out of it. (I am afraid that this is an innate downside of the Okounkov-Vershik approach -- it uses "diagonalizability through positivity" results -- but I'd be happy to learn otherwise!)
- [Mark Wildon, *Representation theory of the symmetric group*](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/Sym/SymGroup2014.pdf) is a really nice combinatorial introduction into the theory. At one point it uses a "Theorem (Brauer)" that is probably not easy to prove elementarily, but by that point a lot has already been proven.
- [Adriano Garsia, *Young seminormal representation: Murphy elements and content evaluation*](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~garsia/somepapers/Youngseminormal.pdf) is an enlightening resource on the seminormal form, which is a very elementary (if rather intransparent and computational) approach to the representations of the symmetric group. Unfortunately, these notes are rough and have errors (e.g., the proof of Proposition 2.3 is wrong; instead, the proposition can be proven by computing $e_{11}^\lambda$ in two different ways: once using (2.26), resulting in $1 / h_\lambda$; once again as the trace of $e_{11}^\lambda$ acting by left multiplication on the $\left(e_{ij}^\mu\right)$ basis of $\mathcal{A}\left(S_n\right)$, resulting in $n_\lambda/n!$). They also omit some proofs (e.g., the "cute argument" referenced in the proof of Theorem 1.2 says that if $f$ is a nilpotent element of a group algebra, then the trace of $f$ must be a multiple of the coefficient of the identity in $f$, but on the other hand, this trace must be $0$ since $f$ is nilpotent).
- Possibly, Chapter 7 of William Fulton, *Young Tableaux*, LMS Student Texts 35, Cambridge University Press 1997 also doesn't rely on the algebraic closure of the base field. (I don't know for sure.)

Likely you'll need to combine different sources.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know a reference that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a splitting field for $S_n$ (i.e. that the endomorphism algebras of the irreducibles are 1-dimensional)? I have found this in Martin Lorenz, Corollary 4.16, but (a) this depends on an exercise, (b) this is not a published book, (c) there must be more classical references! I could not locate them so far.

Comment: I don't know of a reference that proves this right away. You should be able to get it from Garsia's notes (Theorem 2.3 + the fact that the $e_{ij}^\lambda$ form a basis, which is in Remark 2.1), and so I suspect that you can also get it from Rutherford's *Substitutional Analysis* booklet, but as usual you'll have to scratch it out with force.

Comment: Alternatively, you can get it from Wildon's notes, **if** you can find a proof of the fact that any $p\left(n\right)$ pairwise non-isomorphic irreducible $F S_n$-modules (where $p\left(n\right)$ is the number of partitions of $n$) must already cover all possible isomorphism classes of irreducible $F S_n$-modules. This might follow from character orthogonality.

Comment: Ah, yes. So you have found $p\left(n\right)$ pairwise non-isomorphic irreducible $F S_n$-modules, where $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$ (not necessarily algebraically closed). Assume that there is yet another one. Then, the characters of these altogether $p\left(n\right) + 1$ characters of irreducible $F S_n$-modules are mutually orthogonal (since the scalar products, defined via $\left< f, g\right> = \dfrac{1}{\left|S_n\right|} \sum\limits_{\sigma\in S_n} f\left(\sigma\right) g\left(\sigma^{-1}\right)$, are the dimensions of the Hom-spaces, which by Schur's lemma ...

Comment: ... are $0$ for distinct modules and $> 0$ for isomorphic ones) but not orthogonal to themselves. So they are linearly independent, but this contradicts the fact that there are only $p\left(n\right)$ conjugacy classes in $S_n$. All in all, this is an annoyingly patchwork argument, but it should work.

Comment: BTW, if you can turn this into a readable and systematic exposition, the world will be thankful (or at least I will). If you are aiming for constructivity, you should not overstress the irreducibility; instead of "the Specht modules cover all the irreducibles" you should probably say "each nontrivial module has at least one nonzero homomorphism into it from a Specht module" or better "any module whose Hom-spaces from the Specht modules are all $0$ must itself be $0$". But I guess it will get clearer if you start writing.

Comment: Sorry,  but I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I need a complete reference from a published work. In my paper I do not want to spend any time with developing representation theory, but I need a result from it.

Comment: Well, I am afraid this is not readily available in the literature...

Comment: @HeinrichD You can find the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a splitting field, and possibly other things you want, in James & Kerber's book "The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group", Theorem 2.1.12.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Thank you. You may submit this as an answer, if you want to.

Comment: They refer to Curtis-Rainer, which is actually the best book I've seen so far (concerning my question).

Comment: @HeinrichD Actually, looking more carefully, Theorem 2.1.12 states that *every* field is a splitting field. The fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is one is essentially proved earlier in Theorems 2.1.3 and 2.1.11. The reference to Curtis & Reiner is to deduce that fields of prime characteristic are also splitting fields.

Comment: I have asked on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/266291 whether Wildon's treatment of $F S_n$-representations can be made fully elementary.